# Why I cannot fetch the queryString?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I surf to this url:

```
http://localhost:8976/Authorization.htm?oauth_verifier=79Uzx6XtTBLr5bng67YcqoWY&oauth_token=4%2Fld_dV4hLZc1oOGI0YCrqK-qD7VOV
```

My Bll code (**note:** not the code behinde of a asp.net page, but deeper bll code)

tries to fetch the QueryString,

`Request` isn't null

But `QueryString` dictionary has no keys

```
return System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["oauth_token"]
```

Comment: Is it a request to HTML file?

Comment: @EladBenda, are you using any form of URL rewriting in your website, and particularly for this address?

Comment: Why are you trying to fetch query strings in your business layer? That's absolutely wrong. The business layer shouldn't even know what HttpContext is. You should pass this information to the business layer from your UI layer which knows what a query string is. This avoids you the need to use HttpContext.Current.

Comment: @Saeb - My bad, I didn't see that. Answer deleted :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While debugging I see I should use

```
            var query = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.UrlReferrer.Query;
            return query.Substring(...);
```

Now I need to figure out how to use ToDictionary or regex to fetch the right value

Comment: This is not correct. when you use url rewrite, rewrite it with the params.

Comment: then why `UrlReferrer.Query;`?

Comment: this is what I see while debugging

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that there's some rewriting being done somewhere. But if you're sure that there's none, use one of the solutions that I've posted in your [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9748841/fetching-url-using-regex-or-todicitionary).