# fetching url using regex or ToDicitionary

Tags: c#, regex, dictionary

How can I fetch

```
"oauth_verifier=RN9vtxDFfozW51CSTuls0J4C&oauth_token=4%2F3uYq_3vYUSjXaFXtS74B_laW2V4d"
```

RN9vtxDFfozW51CSTuls0J4C

and

4%2F3uYq_3vYUSjXaFXtS74B_laW2V4d

from the string above?

1) Using Regex

2) Using ToDictionary(selector)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Regex:**

Use positive lookarounds:

Regex pattern for fetching `oauth_verifier`'s value:

```
(?<=oauth_verifier=).+(?=&)
```

Regex pattern for fetching `oauth_token`'s value:

```
(?<=oauth_token=).+
```

e.g.:

```
string input = "oauth_verifier=RN9vtxDFfozW51CSTuls0J4C&oauth_token=4%2F3uYq_3vYUSjXaFXtS74B_laW2V4d";
string oauth_verifier = Regex.Match(input, "(?<=oauth_verifier=).+(?=&)").Value;
string oauth_token = Regex.Match(input, "(?<=oauth_token=).+").Value;
```

**ToDictionary**

```
var dic = input.Split('&').ToDictionary( s => s.Remove(s.IndexOf('=')), s => s.Substring(s.IndexOf('=') + 1));
```

Comment: @EladBenda, It matches the value following `oauth_token=`, but doesn't include the `oauth_token=` in the match. This is called _Positive Lookaround_ in regex.

Comment: @EladBenda, also posted the dictionary approach which I prefer.